# Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not working in PHP file hosted in Godaddy domain

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, cors, godaddy-api

I am running an angularjs application in my local system apache(http://localhost:8080). Here am trying to hit an API with post method. My API(http://php.mpect.com/demo/login.php) is hosted in godaddy server domain. Its a PHP file. I included

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

in my php file, but still am getting

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://php.mpect.com/demo/login.php. 
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
>   Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

I am new to php and godaddy server. How can I solve this? Is there any way to include headers in godaddy domain? sorry for my english. Can anyone please provide me solution code to acheive this CORS problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not totally clear to me, you've edited the file at `http://php.myui.com/demo/login.php` to include that header line?

Comment: I am not understanding what you are are trying to say. I have edited my question for more clear information

Comment: A common mistake when trying to configure CORS is to place the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the page the user is requesting _from_ rather than the destination URL. So I'm asking if you placed that header on the `localhost` url or the `php.myui.com` url.

Comment: I added that in php.mpect.com url (sorry for the wrong api before "myui")

Comment: An `options` request on `http://php.mpect.com/demo1/login.php` does not return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` other HTTP-Methods does.

Comment: Do you have any whitespace or echos before the header line?

Comment: http://php.mpect.com/demo/login.php.. Can you try this link please @lin

Comment: No I don't have any whitespace or echo before my header @ Felix

Comment: <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
include_once("index.php");
$month=date('m');
$day=date('d');
$hour=date('H');
$minute=date('i');
$seconds=date('s');
$session_id=randgen(4).$month.randgen(4).$day.randgen(4).$hour.randgen(4).$minute.randgen(4).$seconds;
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');?>

Comment: @RohithDeveloper try it yourself: https://www.hurl.it/

Comment: Now it showing Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * right @Lin. Now I got my response also if I enter parameters, But if I hit it from localhost it showing above mentioned error. What I made mistake. Is there any other things need to add for my php file.

Answer (score -1):

Add the configuration into your `.htaccess` file and you will be fine. This will ensure that the important CORS headers will set on any request. Ensure you have enabled **mod_headers** on apache2.

```
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
```

Comment: you'll also need to make sure the apache module header or headers, I forget, is enabled for this to work

Comment: How can I enable apache module in godaddy?

Comment: @RohithDeveloper https://www.godaddy.com/help/enabling-apache-or-php-modules-using-easyapache-6237 maybe like this?

Comment: @RohithDeveloper have you been able to fix it?

Comment: No @lin, When I try to hit https://mydomainname:2087/, It showing me "This site can’t be reached".